# MySQL stores greek using latin

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to store greek characters in my database and instead of:

```
ονομα i get &omicron ;&nu ;&omicron ;&mu ;&alpha ;
```

In my php code I added

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
```

This should fix the problem how ever the problem its still there.

Is it something with the encoding of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use utf-8, you should use utf-8 everywhere. Not only in the response Header and the database connection. This includes table character set/collation. *And* also your php-script files if you have raw strings entered there.

If you took the string from your browser result, it looks like it was html-encoded. Some functions like `htmlentities` require you to set a charset. Prior to PHP 5.4 it did **not** default to UTF-8 so you should make sure to set it accordingly.

You can revert the chance using the function `html_entity_decode`.